# Client side error, I guess related to utf-8 or something related to form tags. But can't solve it

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, utf-8, http-status-code-400

I am trying to submit form request with Spring MVC form and add data to db with Hibernate. But it shows such error ***"The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)."***
I researched this question and looked through almost all related questions here, but can't find appropriate for me solution.

My jsp file

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>

<head>
    <title>New Plan Form</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/new-plan-form.css">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
    
</head>


<body>

    <h2>New Plan Form</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <form:form action="saveNewPlan" modelAttribute="newPlan" method="POST" acceptCharset="utf-8">
    
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                    <label for="fname">Title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <form:input path="title" id="title" name="title"
                        placeholder="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
            

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                    <label for="subject">Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <form:textarea path="description" id="description"
                        name="description" placeholder="Write about plan in detail"
                        style="height:200px" />

                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                    <label for="lname">Begin Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <form:input path="beginDate" id="beginDate" name="beginDate"
                        placeholder="When you will begin to realize this plan" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                          $("#beginDate").datetimepicker();
                        </script>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-25">
                    <label for="lname">End Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <form:input path="endDate" id="endDate" name="endDate"
                        placeholder="Until when you should finish this plan" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                          $("#endDate").datetimepicker();
                        </script>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>

        </form:form>

     </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My request handler method for that form action in my UserController class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/saveNewPlan")
    public String savePlan(@ModelAttribute("newPlan") Plan thePlan) {
        
        planService.savePlan(thePlan);
        
        
        return "home-page";
    }
}
```

And the ViewResolver part of my Config file

```
package com.todolist.webbapp.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.todolist.webbapp")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");

        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html ; charset=UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Comment: Remove acceptCharset="utf-8" and try

Comment: Actually my code was without acceptCharset part, I added it newly in order to solve the problem. I found about Charset here, but it didn't work for me.